# How to get Key from firebase databse in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I am working on an application where i need to get the keys from the realtime databse's collection i have stored users id's in keys inside the collection. And I am performing a firestore query on the id's I will get from those keys. So when i am trying to get the keys from the realtime databse in a string the string is null here "whereEqualTo("uid", recentUserId)". How can i get the keys so that i can perform the query.

```
String recentUserId;

// Code to get the user id's from the realtime databse stored in keys
firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Recent_Chats").child(auth.getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

             recentUserId = snapshot1.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey therere" + recentUserId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
});


//      Code to get the relevent ids user data from firestore
Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("uid", recentUserId);
query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

        List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
        for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
            User obj = d.toObject(User.class);
            userArrayList.add(obj);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Realtime Database Structure:
[image]

I tried some ways, but did not get how to get keys.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. When you run your code in a debugger, what is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading data from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) is **asynchronous**, and the way you have written your code now means that the query on Firestore will happen before the `recentUserId = snapshot1.getKey();` has ever been set.

To ensure the correct order, all code that needs data from the database has to be *inside* the `onDataChange` that fires when the data is loaded, or be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

So the simplest fix is to move the loading from Firestore into the `onDataChange` like this:

```
String recentUserId;

// Code to get the user id's from the realtime databse stored in keys
firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Recent_Chats").child(auth.getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            recentUserId = snapshot1.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey therere" + recentUserId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //     Code to get the relevent ids user data from firestore
            Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("uid", recentUserId);
            query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                        User obj = d.toObject(User.class);
                        userArrayList.add(obj);
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also see my longer explanations here: [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519) and [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)